# dependent picklist in Visualforce issue (apex action method must be a page reference)

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

I am trying to create a custom dependent picklist in Visualforce (I cannot use the standard field tags because the guest site user does not have access to the User object). I am using the selectOption tag as well as actionSupport to reference my method in a custom controller and I am stuck. I made sure there is a default value in the primary picklist. I've searched the boards and tried to make sure my actionSupport is correct. I also put the entire thing within the apex:actionRegion tag and that did not help.  I had my developer friend take a look and he could not fix it either. The error I am getting is that I view the page, enter data and select an option within the first list. I then get an error that the apex action method must be a page reference. I don't actually know what that means or how to fix it. Here is my controller (at least the relevant part). VF page below.

```
    public with sharing class CommunitiesSelfRegController {
    /*** An apex page controller that supports self registration of users in communities that allow self registration */
    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String phone {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String location {get; set{location = value;}}
    public List<SelectOption> customerOrgs{get;set;}
    public String selectedCustomerOrg {get; set;}

    public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {

    location='108 Charter Oak';
    getCustomerOrgs();
}

public void setCustomerOrgs(List<SelectOption> orgs) {
        this.customerOrgs = orgs;
    }

public List<SelectOption> getCustomerOrgs(){
    List<SelectOption> locs= new List<SelectOption>();
    if(location==null)
        return null;
    else
    {
        if(location.contains('Aerospace Elementary School')){
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Aerospace Elementary School','Aerospace Elementary School'));
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
        }
        if(location.contains('108 Charter Oak')){
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Student Services', 'Student Services'));
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
        }
        if(location.contains('147 Charter Oak')){
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Business Services','Business Services'));
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Facilities','Facilities'));
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Food Services','Food Services'));
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Human Resources','Human Resources'));
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Operations','Operations'));
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
        }
        if(location.contains('155 Wyllys Street')){
            locs.add(new SelectOption('CREC Transporation','CREC Transporation'));
            locs.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
        }
    } 
    return locs;
}
```

`
Visualforce page (just the relevant part):

> `<apex:outputLabel value="Location" for="Location"/>
>       <apex:actionRegion>
>        <apex:outputPanel id="one">
>         <apex:selectList value="{!location}" title="Location" multiselect="false" size="3" onchange="{!Location}">
>         <apex:selectOption itemValue="Aerospace Elementary School" itemLabel="Aerospace Elementary School"/>
>         <apex:selectOption itemValue="108 Charter Oak" itemLabel="108 Charter Oak"/>
>         <apex:selectOption itemValue="147 Charter Oak" itemlabel="147 Charter Oak"/>
>         <apex:selectOption itemvalue="155 Wyllys Street" itemLabel="155 Wyllys Street"/>
>         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getcustomerOrgs}" reRender="two"/>
>         </apex:selectList>
>         <br/>
>        <apex:outputPanel >Location: {!location}</apex:outputPanel>
>        <br/>
>       <apex:outputPanel id="two">
>        <b>Choose a Customer Organization</b>
>        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!customerOrgs}">
>        <apex:selectOptions value="{!CustomerOrgs}"/>
>        </apex:selectList>
>        </apex:outputPanel>
>        </apex:outputPanel>
>         </apex:actionRegion>`

Comment: Please post the error message verbatim.

Comment: Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: core.apexpages.el.adapters.ApexListELAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming your method to something like `loadCompanyOrgs` and returning a `PageReference` as the error describes. It looks like you can't use a `getter` as an `action`.

```
public PageReference loadCompanyOrgs()
{
    // perform logic
    // return null (causes rerender)
}
```

Comment: I think OP can dispense with action= altogether as the getter referenced by output panel with id="two" should just use as lookup key the value set by the first selectList value=.  OnChange with rerender will send the value of the selectList to the controller and rerender will cause page refresh. action method seems superfluous

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to move the id="two" to the select list. It was a little hard to test your code since it wasn't complete, but I was able to get it to work with this code.

Note, I would recommend storing the locations and orgs in custom objects and querying them instead of hard coding everything in code.

```
public class PicklistController {
    public String location {get; set;}
    public String selectedCustomerOrg {get; set;}

    public PicklistController() { }

    public List<SelectOption> getLocations() {
        List<SelectOption> locs= new List<SelectOption>();
        locs.add(new SelectOption('', '--Select Location--'));
        locs.add(new SelectOption('Aerospace Elementary School','Aerospace Elementary School'));
        locs.add(new SelectOption('108 Charter Oak', '108 Charter Oak'));
        locs.add(new SelectOption('147 Charter Oak', '147 Charter Oak'));
        locs.add(new SelectOption('155 Wyllys Street', '155 Wyllys Street'));
        return locs;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getCustomerOrgs() {
        List<SelectOption> locs= new List<SelectOption>();
        locs.add(new SelectOption('', '--Select Organization--'));
        if (location != null) {
            if(location.contains('Aerospace Elementary School')) {
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Aerospace Elementary School','Aerospace Elementary School'));
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
            }
            if(location.contains('108 Charter Oak')) {
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Student Services', 'Student Services'));
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
            }
            if(location.contains('147 Charter Oak')) {
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Business Services','Business Services'));
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Facilities','Facilities'));
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Food Services','Food Services'));
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Human Resources','Human Resources'));
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Operations','Operations'));
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
            }
            if(location.contains('155 Wyllys Street')) {
                locs.add(new SelectOption('CREC Transporation','CREC Transporation'));
                locs.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
            }
        }
        system.debug(locs);
        return locs;
    }

    public Pagereference DummyCall() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The page:

```
<apex:page controller="PicklistController" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Select your location" />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Location and Organization">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Location"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
                        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!location}">
                            <apex:selectoptions value="{!Locations}"/>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="org"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Organization" />
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
                        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedCustomerOrg}" id="org">
                            <apex:selectoptions value="{!customerOrgs}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: With the custom object option, I thought that might work as well but it seems like in my case I'd need a junction object, as the orgs could belong to many locations. Is that what you were thinking?

Also thank you for the thorough answer. Your code works beautifully. I can't get it to work within my page though. For some reason it is not re-rendering after selecting the first option.  Could it be affected by my inputText fields?

Comment: Try getting rid of public customerOrgs property and the setCustomerOrgs method. I think they might be confusing things. Also remove the action from your actionSupport tags.

Comment: Yes, you might need a junction object to link orgs to locations.